# Wireshark API's available?

Tags: c, wireshark

I have a new project. Here's the idea. I take my trace as an input and my tool should give me all the connections in that trace. And then I have to do several things on those connections.

My question is - I know tshark is one API which I can use to get this information.

Are there any other API's available, especially in C which I can use for this purpose?

Comment: Please write the question clearly , title mentions wireshark but no mention of it in the actual question.

Comment: So you're trying to write a tool which parses wireshark trace files or something?

Comment: Exactly. That's what I have to do.

Comment: Have you tried the googles? I hear it's really good for finding documentation, or perhaps the relevant mailing lists.

Comment: Thanks, tbert. Smart.!! I also heard StackOverflow is really good for finding documentation or relevant mailing list.

Comment: How about https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/12/libwireshark-library-c-example/ ?